# Product of two elliptic isometries with distincts centers

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry

I'd like to know why is the product of two elliptic isometries of the hyperbolic upper plan (or  of the unitary disk) with distincts fixed points is parabolic or hyperbolic?

PS: I only need it for dimension $2$ $ie$ in $PSL(2,\mathbb{R})$

Thank you!

Comment: It depends on the fixed points and angles of rotation. The product can also be elliptic.

Comment: Ok so let say one isometry as the center of the disk as fixed point, how could I show that the product isn't elliptic?

Comment: Knowing one center is not enough, the product could be elliptic.

Comment: Oh ok and if they would have same angle? I´m refering to Case 4 page 136 in the following Paper : Pierre de la Harpe, Free groups in Linear groups, L'enseignement mathématique, t.29 (1983)

Comment: I do not know that paper but even for equal angles the product can be elliptic (even of the same angle as the other two).

Comment: Really? I´m confused then, because in the paper what they do is:
Take 2 elliptic transformation `g` and `h` such that `g^2` is not the identity and such that they don't share fixed points.
Then conjugate `g` to get a rotation `g'` with center the origin and consider `k:=hg'h^-1`.
Finally they give some strange argument to say that there is a point in the border of the disc that is sent to same point by `k` and `g'`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what's happening:

Let $p, q$ be distinct points in the hyperbolic plane $H^2$ and let $\alpha, \beta$ be the angles of rotation of elliptic elements $f, g$ fixing $p$ and $q$ (both $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are computed counterclockwise). Then $h=g\circ f$ is elliptic iff the following holds: There exists a finite hyperbolic triangle with one side $pq$ and the angles $\alpha/2, \beta/2$ at $q, p$ respectively, and lying to the left from the oriented segment $pq$. If we fix the angles $\alpha, \beta$ in advance and take $pq$ sufficiently long then this triangle will not exist, as its sides $s$ (from $p$) and $t$ (from $q$) will be disjoint in $H^2$ (they will intersect either on the boundary or beyond, if you work in the Klein model).  In order to prove this statement, consider three isometric reflections $r_1, r_2, r_3$ in the sides $pq, s$ and $t$ of "would be triangle'' defined above. Then $r_2\circ r_1= g, r_1\circ r_3=f$. The composition $h= r_2 \circ r_3$. This transformation is elliptic iff the geodesics $s, t$ intersect in $H^2$.

Comment: Ok I get the proof of the statement but I don't really see in my case how they get that we can't find such triangle  with `k` and `g'^-1`. How could I notice that the centers are "far enough" to get a non elliptic isometry?

Comment: @WrabbitW Use dual hyperbolic cosine law to show that a triangle with two fixed angles and long enough side between does not exist.

Comment: Hi, I'm so sorry to answer so late... I found and other way to show what I wanted (with more calculus on matrices) I could not see the geometric argument. Thank you a lot for your time!